# How to add arbitrary node/edge attributes for export as Graphml file?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to add arbitrary attributes to a graph `G` that I can access in other software, after exporting as a graphml file. If I export `Export["graph.graphml", G]`, I simply get the information from the adjacency matrix.

Is it possible to add more attributes to the graph, like "edgecolor", "edgeweight", "nodesize", etc... that I can access after exporting?

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica does not produce standards compliant GraphML files. Many other systems will plainly refuse to read Mathematica-written GraphML. Even those that do read it, often cannot use the properties because they are in the form of Mathematica expressions converted into strings.  The GraphML specification is quite clear about what data types are allowed and how they should be stored ... that's not followed.

This is why [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) includes a separate GraphML exporter.  I suggest you use it.

You do not need to do anything else than add the properties to the graph before export.

Example:

```
<<IGraphM`

g = Graph[{Property[1, "Name" -> "Alice"], Property[2, "Name" -> "Bob"]}, 
       {Property[1 <-> 2, EdgeWeight -> 123.5]}];
```

Here's what `Export` produces:

```
ExportString[g, "GraphML"]
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<graphml>
 <key id='nodeKey1'
     for='node'
     attr.name='Name'
     attr.type='String' />
 <key id='nodeKey2'
     for='node'
     attr.name='VertexCoordinates'
     attr.type='String' />
 <key id='edgeKey1'
     for='edge'
     attr.name='EdgeWeight'
     attr.type='String' />
 <graph id='Graph1'
     edgedefault='undirected'>
  <node id='1'>
   <data key='nodeKey1'>Alice</data>
   <data key='nodeKey2'>List[1.`, 0.`]</data>
  </node>
  <node id='2'>
   <data key='nodeKey1'>Bob</data>
   <data key='nodeKey2'>List[-1.`, 0.`]</data>
  </node>
  <edge id='e1'
      source='1'
      target='2'>
   <data key='edgeKey1'>123.5`</data>
  </edge>
 </graph>
</graphml>
```

Major issues:

- Does not specify the schema, so about half of the software out there does not even recognize this as GraphML.
- Everything has `attr.type='String'`.  `string` would be valid, but `String` is not. Some software is forgiving, but your number will still come out as strings. Moreover, they will have a `` ` `` sign appended. Even if the target software has a feature to convert string attributes into numbers, it will probably trip up on this `` ` ``.
- It exports vertex coordinates as `List[...]`, again put in a string. No other software than Mathematica will read this, so it's rather useless.

Here's what IGraph/M's `IGExport` function produces:

```
IGExportString[g, "GraphML"]
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- created by IGraph/M, http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM -->
<graphml xmlns='http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns'
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xsi:schemaLocation='http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd'>
 <key for='edge'
     id='e_EdgeWeight'
     attr.name='EdgeWeight'
     attr.type='double' />
 <key for='node'
     id='v_Name'
     attr.name='Name'
     attr.type='string' />
 <graph id='Graph'
     edgedefault='undirected'>
  <node id='1'>
   <data key='v_Name'>Alice</data>
  </node>
  <node id='2'>
   <data key='v_Name'>Bob</data>
  </node>
  <edge source='1'
      target='2'>
   <data key='e_EdgeWeight'>123.5</data>
  </edge>
 </graph>
</graphml>
```

Notice the correct XML schema and the appropriate attribute types (`string` and `double`).

`IGExport` will not include Mathematica-specific properties such as `VertexStyle` or `VertexCoordinates`. If you need to export these, copy them into into custom properties with `IGEdgeMap` and `IGVertexMap`.  For example,

```
IGExportString[
 g // IGVertexMap[First, "x" -> GraphEmbedding] // 
  IGVertexMap[Last, "y" -> GraphEmbedding],
 "GraphML"
 ]
```

Snippet from the output:

```xml
 <key for='node'
     id='v_x'
     attr.name='x'
     attr.type='double' />
 <key for='node'
     id='v_y'
     attr.name='y'
     attr.type='double' />
```

...

```xml
  <node id='2'>
   <data key='v_Name'>Bob</data>
   <data key='v_x'>-1.</data>
   <data key='v_y'>0.</data>
  </node>
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. I seem to have succesfully installed IGraphM, but am a bit confused as to how to actually export my graph to a .graphml now. Does `IGExportString[g, "GraphML"]` actually export a graphml file? Where does it put it?

Comment: Hmm I'm guessing my installation was not successful since `IGVersion[]` returns `Out[5]=IGVersion[]`...

Comment: `IGExportString` produces a string with the content of the file. `IGExport[file, graph, "GraphML"]` writes to a file. Just like `ExportString` vs `Export`.

Comment: If `IGVersion[]` returns the same, then the package was not loaded.  Did you evaluate ``<<IGraphM` ``?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize I actually needed to include the "<<". Seems to have been loaded now. Will give it a shot again. Thanks!

Comment: @theQman Did you manage to get it to work? There's also a new version released today, [please upgrade!](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM#installation)

Comment: I will update and give it a try this afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SetProperty`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetProperty.html) to define custom properties for vertices and edges:

```
SeedRandom[1]
g1 = RandomGraph[{5, 9}];
nodesizes = RandomReal[1, 5];
nodecolors = Table[Hue[RandomReal[]], {5}];
edgecolors = Table[Hue[RandomReal[]], {EdgeCount[g1]}];
edgeweights = Table[Hue[RandomReal[]], {EdgeCount[g1]}];
g1 = Fold[SetProperty[{#, #2}, 
     {"nodesize" -> nodesizes[[#2]], 
     "nodecolors" -> nodecolors[[#2]]}] &, g1, VertexList[g1]]
g1 = Fold[SetProperty[{#, EdgeList[g1][[#2]]}, 
     {"edgeweights" -> edgeweights[[#2]], 
      "edgecolors" -> edgecolors[[#2]]}] &, g1, Range@EdgeCount[g1]];

Export[ "testg1.graphml", g1];
Import["testg1.graphml", {{"EdgeAttributes", "VertexAttributes"}} ]
```

> {{{{edgecolors->Hue[0.4806592451638043], edgeweights->Hue[0.13062341735313532]}, {edgecolors->Hue[0.8946098545557493],edgeweights->Hue[0.3209754265030236]}, {edgecolors->Hue[0.007444617743282977],edgeweights->Hue[0.8155119957231329]}, {edgecolors->Hue[0.741601922199022],edgeweights->Hue[0.8476492996330929]}, {edgecolors->Hue[0.2513397456769364],edgeweights->Hue[0.33273161943614116]}, {edgecolors->Hue[0.974394727015687],edgeweights->Hue[0.9878977012321821]}, {edgecolors->Hue[0.8630367069779892],edgeweights->Hue[0.7838347676768282]}, {edgecolors->Hue[0.06746415411924045],edgeweights->Hue[0.5943838055231356]}, {edgecolors->Hue[0.5352050858030937],edgeweights->Hue[0.16349937322060293]}}},
>   {{{nodecolors->Hue[0.1698241636720852], nodesize->0.3788643945880994, VertexCoordinates->List[0., 0.6036428791280587]},
>   {nodecolors->Hue[0.45535872569513947], nodesize->0.9416988272914835, VertexCoordinates->List[1.006943513923487, 0.]},
>   {nodecolors->Hue[0.7542499504147353], nodesize->0.2942640188247172, VertexCoordinates->List[0.8294432880449293, 0.6024873029730559]},
>    {nodecolors->Hue[0.2682911877382106], nodesize->0.18827366005036095, VertexCoordinates->List[1.008260262516205, 1.2072356645553475]},
>   {nodecolors->Hue[0.14737721617315191], nodesize->0.7615290315044017, VertexCoordinates->List[1.8707672937283246, 0.602648036371213]}}}}

Comment: I was able to run this code with the same results as you, but I didn't see the custom attributes when I opened the file in other graph software. Any ideas?

Comment: @theQman, I haven't used it with other software. Bases on Szabolcs's answer, mathematica-produced graphml files do not work as expected in other graph software.